# javascript cookies not working if page not reload

Tags: javascript

```
**javascript cookies not working in firefox suppose**
<script>
```

document.cookie="Language=javascript";

```
**this is working in single tab fine in firefox but if i open multiple tab 
after that if i changed any values of cookies it will not getting current 
changed values** 

**suppose from developer console if i change cookies like this**
```

document.cookie="Language=PHP";

```
**then go to another tab then but not reload and  print it will not print** 
"Language=PHP"
**its printing "Language=javascript"**


<script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I always setCookie and getCookie functions from w3c school.
And it works fine with all browsers. 
Try it. 
Here
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: yes you  right . but plz check this link on chrome and firefox . https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp    open this link in two tabs in chrome .on first tab click on create cookie1,2 button then go to next tab then click on display all cookie button you will get alert of cookie. but when you this thing on firefox you will not get cookie on second tab. if you not refresh second tab in firefox.